# Bug in the favourite button

Tags: bug, status-completed

This is not a question. I am new to chemistry stack exchange and I don't know how I can report a bug. Hovering over the "favourite question" button always pops up a message saying"This is a favourite question" even if it is not

Comment: I get the same message, weird.

Comment: This is something that is the same on the whole network, so [meta.se] might have been a good place to ask it. I agree the wording could be better. The developers look at questions that are tagged [meta-tag:bug] so this will also work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was indeed confusing. I have tweaked it a bit and that's how it looks now, 
hopefully it's more clear:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I think this is intended, it's just slightly bad wording. What it says is:

> This is a favourite question (click again to undo)

I interpret this as saying, if you click this button it will be a favourite question and if you click it again it will be unfavourited. I agree that this is possibly not the best way of expressing it, particularly if you are not a native English speaker.

Comment: "Mark this as a favorite question (click again to undo)" would be a lot better.